Should I apologise to a professor after a gift authorship attempt, which they refused?
(I am a PhD student) I recently worked on a paper using a computational methodology developed by Professor X and my manuscript was published on a preprint server.
My supervisor, Professor Y, is actively seeking collaborations and emailed Professor X to discuss potential opportunities. After reading my manuscript, Professor X was pleased and agreed to discuss further, but did not provide any help or contributions to the paper.
Professor Y then met with Professor X without me to discuss the potential for collaboration. Afterwards, Professor Y informed me that we should list Professor X as a co-author on the final version of my paper. I was not comfortable with this situation but Professor Y quickly shut that by stating that they had already discussed this with Professor X and everything was agreed.
After I emailed Professor X asking about their credentials to be included as a co-author on the paper. Professor X then replied to both Professor Y and me, clearly refusing the gift authorship.
I am wondering if I should email Professor X again to explain my perspective, as my reputation is at stake.
For more context about my circumstances, please refer to my two previous questions.

Careful! If you explanation directly or indirectly puts blame on Professor Y, this will likely damage your reputation as well!

It's not clear what you mean by "gift authorship" or if this even is gift authorship, whatever that might be. You don't share Professors Y's motivation for requesting Professor X be added as an author. An un-generous reading of your post implies that Professor Y is behaving unethically in the interest of getting a "collaboration". But there's not enough evidence from the OP to determine this. This sounds like something Professor Y needs to deal with, not you.

How long ago was this? I'd expect Y to respond (to both of you).

It sounds like you screwed something up for Prof. Y. Prof. Y will not be amused with you going past Y to talk to X without asking Y first.

@stackoverblown Oh yes sorry that I "screwed something up" for him, what should I do then? Sacrifice every inches of my being to please my supervisor?

I would reply with a very simple apology (like "sorry for the confusion") and a statement confirming you understand their request (like "we will not include you as an author").
Do not try to "explain your perspective", your reputation is not "at stake" here, just don't include them as an author and move on.

agree. As it is quite possible that it is just miscommunication/misunderstanding. e.g. your advisor thinks those discussion is insightful enough to be consideration as contribution, but the other professor does not think so.

It also depends on how long ago this occurred.  If this happened some time ago I wouldn't contact them at all.

@MahaliSindy It could be different (sub)field norms as well; where Prof. X's contribution merits authorship in Prof. Y's area, but not X's, if we want to be charitable

The most important thing here is to keep it simple and avoid overcomplicating the situation when it could all account to "just miscommunication".

I agree with the gist of the answer. But can you explain why you think OP's reputation is not at stake? Isn't OP reasonable to be concerned that Professor X might form a negative opinion of them based on interpreting their email as an offer of gift authorship, that is, essentially a kind of bribe? And based on this description, aren't both OP's reputation and the reputation of Prof. Y, at least to some minor extent, "at stake"? There could very well be negative reputational effects from someone thinking I offered them a bribe. (From a practical point of view your advice sounds good though.)

Personally, I think it would be wise to do so, but without getting into an argument with Y. It might be enough to say that there was a miscommunication and you misunderstood the situation.
Since X has shown interest in collaboration, you could also follow up on that and ask how you might proceed.
I'll guess that Y misrepresented something to you, but you don't need to get into an argument over that. If pressed, say to Y that X told you directly that they don't want authorship here.

If pressed, say to Y that X told you directly that they don't want authorship here - OP mentioned that Professor X then replied to both Professor Y and me, clearly refusing the gift authorship →  Y already knows.

@WoJ it's not unreasonable to suggest, that if Y pressed before they would do it again. The fact that they know IMO is immaterial to the discussion.

Discuss this issue with Prof Y; asking them in private over email or if possible, in person. State that the Prof X has declined the authorship and what should you do. Since they clearly are in contact, it is their responsibility to solve this issue. If Prof X sounds confrontational about this, mention it as well. Keep in mind that Prof Y could very well be busy and missed the tone of the email.
Remember you are doing what you are told, there might be many dynamics you are not aware of. There are cases where this could be unethical behavior; however, there are cases where this could very well be a miscommunication like Prof Y invites Prof X to improve the paper but Prof X rejected with a vague answer which Prof Y takes as a yes. You do not have the complete knowledge to judge and act. Your reputation cannot be tarnished by following requests from your supervisor where there are many unknowns on your part.
In academia, always assume someone has good intentions unless you know the whole story.

What I can discern is that Prof Y is disciplined and quite strict. There is not much evidence about how they will act in this situation. Neither asking 9-5 work nor asking student to work the way they want display much of their character towards interpersonal communication.

The situation appears quite clear so that X can make a close enough guess what actually happened. There is no need to complicate things by going into the details with X.
If you want to reply in a positive way, you could say that you value X's perspective on the authorship issue and that you understand that they think that their contribution so far does not merit authorship, so you will handle it accordingly. You could then say that you are looking forward to future collaboration (if appropriate).
Personally, I think you could also say something like that X's reply honors them in order to express that you appreciate X's academic integrity. It makes sense to acknowledge that X is doing the right thing. If you fear that this implies too much about Y, you would better skip this, of course.
This would result in a reply not longer than three sentences.

I think that saying to someone more senior that "X's reply honors them in order to express that you appreciate X's academic integrity" is likely to land very strangely

@deee Especially after the attempt at a gift authorship. "Well, the bribe didn't work. Let's try flattery next".

It is super weird to jam your own thoughts into Prof. X's brain. Just leave it out. Do not try to guess what Prof. X's thought process. This actually would tell Prof. X that the OP does not think Prof. X merit an authorship. Prof. X does not need the OP's judgement.
